# Executing in-parallel groups of in-order blocking tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I've been mulling over this for some time, and am learning more and more about threads, executors, etc. as I go. I have a rough understanding of executors and threads, but am feeling a bit stuck.

Here's what I'm trying to do.

There are Commands, and there are Actions.
A Command is named and can be invoked arbitrarily by an user, for example !playsong, !cheer, etc.
An Action is a thing that sends work to a service; for example asking the websocket client to send a new message, or asking IRC client to send a new message, etc.

When a command is executed, it executes its Actions in-order one-after-another.

For example, the !cheer command might have four Actions:

1. Make a websocket request, and wait for a successful response (ex: show a scene-item in OBS)
2. Send an IRC message (ex: send a chat message). Once sent then,
3. Wait for 1-3 seconds (ex: waiting on a video to finish playing). Once wait has finished, then
4. Make another websocket request (ex: hide the scene-item from step 1)

Not only must these execute in-order BUT we cannot have all of them start at once either (Actions 1, 2, and 4 complete first and then Action 3 completes last); each Action depends on its predecessor being completed first.

On top of all this, Commands can be submitted arbitrarily by clients at any time and must not block each other. For example, !longcommand can be started but won't block !shortcommand from starting (assuming the underlying services aren't blocked).

Here's what I'm thinking of doing:

I know I can use Future/Callable to block pending the result of execution on a given Thread, so each Action should return a Future when run (the Future coming from its respective Service it uses). Then, I can simply call the actions one-by-one in a blocking way like this on a command to ensure they execute in order and each waits on the other to finish:

```
class ExecutableCommand implments Runnable {
  // omitted for brevity

  run() {
    for(Action action:command.getActions()) {
    action.run().get();
  } 

}
```

But how would I handle executing commands?
I guess I'd submit each Command via an executor, maybe a ThreadPoolExecutor like this as each is submitted?

```
class ExecutorServiceWrapper {

  private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newThreadPoolExecutor(4);
  
  void submit(ExecutableCommand command) {
    executorService.submit(command)
  }

}
```

And then each client ofc would simply keep a reference to ExecutorServiceWrapper and call it in response to events that trigger them:

```
class FromChatHandler() {
  private final ExecutorServiceWrapper masterQueue;

  onMessage(String message) {
    Command command = // parse what command to lookup from message
    masterQueue.submit(command)
  }
}

@RestController // or whatever
class MyController() {
  private final ExecutorServiceWrapper masterQueue;

  @Post
  executeCommandByName(String commandName) {
    Command command = // lookup command
    masterQueue.submit(command)
  }
}

class directHandler() {
  private final ExecutorServiceWrapper masterQueue;

  handle(Command command) {
    Command command = // build the command given the message
    masterQueue.submit(command)
  }
}
```

I'm assuming that since each command is being submitted to the executor that each is going to its own Thread so it won't block the others.

But I'm not sure if I should be doing what I'm doing above with ExecutableCommand and executing each action within the Command like I am.

Plus, I'm not sure if it would handle this case:
The threadpool is fixed at 5 threads.
5 commands have been executed. They're long running and use different services, but the underlying services are not blocked and can still accept work.
Somebody tries to execute a 6th command -- they should not be blocked, because the underlying services can still accept work.

Is there some better way to do this? Am I on the right track?

Comment: You may be looking for the `CompletableFuture#then` methods.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read up a bit on that!

...Though, how would I handle the above scenario where the thread pool is exhausted for commands (due to having many/long-running Actions), but the underlying services are available to execute actions?

Comment: Hej @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- , I've edited my example to include something that seems to roughly do the job (though by no means does it provide the granularity I'm looking for). Do you have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more time on this, I've come up with a few possible solutions using either Executors or Futures. Not sure yet which would be better than the other, but since I know I can extend ThreadPoolExecutor (say, to add a pause feature) I'll probably lean towards Executors.

Otherwise, if anyone has comments they're always welcome!

I'm keeping both solutions in my GH for now (), but I'll put them below as well.
https://github.com/TinaTiel/concurrency-learning

### Futures Implementation

```
package futures;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CommandActionExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Initialize some starting params
        Random random = new Random();
        int maxActions = 20;
        int maxCommands = 5;

        // Generate some commands, with a random number of actions.
        // We'll use the indexes as the command and action names to keep it simple/readable
        List<Command> commands = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Integer c = 0; c < maxCommands; c++) {
            Command command = new Command(String.format("%d", c+1));
            for(Integer a = 0; a < random.nextInt(maxActions); a++) {
                Action action = new Action(random, String.format("%d", a+1));
                command.addAction(action);
            }
            commands.add(command);
        }

        // Print out the commands we'll execute, again to keep the results readable/understandable
        System.out.println("Commands to execute: \n" + commands.stream().map(Command::toString).collect(Collectors.joining("\n")) + "\n");

        // Build a Future that tries to execute all commands (supplied as Futures) in an arbitrary order
        try {
            CompletableFuture.allOf(commands.stream()
                    .map((Function<Command, CompletableFuture<Void>>) CompletableFuture::runAsync)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
                    .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)
            ).get();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
//        commands.get(0).run(); // sanity check one of the command's actions run as expected

        // When we execute the results, the actions should be executed in-order within a command at some point in the future
        // (not started all at once), so something like:
        // 0  Command-2:Action-1 scheduled at 34
        // 0  Command-1:Action-1 scheduled at 21
        // 0  Command-3:Action-1 scheduled at 4
        // 4  Command-3:Action2 scheduled at ...
        // 21 Command-1:Action-2 scheduled at ...
        // 34 Command-1-Action-2 scheduled at ...
        // ...
        // Now how to test this...Maybe with JUnit inOrder.verify(...).run() ?

    }

    public static class Action implements Runnable {

        private Command command;
        private final Random random;
        private final String name;

        public Action(Random random, String name) {
            this.random = random;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void setCommand(Command command) {
            this.command = command;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            // Simply sleep for a random period of time. This simulates pieces of work being done (network request, etc.)
            long msTime = random.nextInt(1000);
            System.out.println(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ": Command-" + command.name + ":Action-" + name + " executing on Thread '" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "' executing for " + msTime + "ms");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(msTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Action{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    public static class Command implements Runnable {

        private final String name;
        private final List<Action> actions = new ArrayList<>();

        public Command(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void addAction(Action action) {
            action.setCommand(this);
            actions.add(action);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // If there are no actions, then do nothing
            if(actions.isEmpty()) return;

            // Build up a chain of futures.
            // Looks like we have to build them up in reverse order, so start with the first action...
            CompletableFuture<Void> completableFuture = CompletableFuture.runAsync(actions.remove(0));

            // ...And then reverse the list and build the rest of the chain
            // (yes we could execute backwards...but it's not common and I/others probably don't like to reason about it)
            Collections.reverse(actions);
            for(int i=0; i< actions.size(); i++) {
                completableFuture.thenRun(actions.get(i));
            }

            // Execute our chain
            try {
                completableFuture.get();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Command{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", actions=" + actions +
                    '}';
        }
    }

}
```

#### Results

Output and schedule is as-expected, but it appears Futures use the ForkJoinPool.

```
Commands to execute: 
Command{name='1', actions=[Action{name='1'}, Action{name='2'}, Action{name='3'}]}
Command{name='2', actions=[Action{name='1'}, Action{name='2'}, Action{name='3'}, Action{name='4'}, Action{name='5'}, Action{name='6'}]}
Command{name='3', actions=[Action{name='1'}, Action{name='2'}, Action{name='3'}, Action{name='4'}, Action{name='5'}, Action{name='6'}, Action{name='7'}]}
Command{name='4', actions=[Action{name='1'}, Action{name='2'}, Action{name='3'}, Action{name='4'}, Action{name='5'}, Action{name='6'}]}
Command{name='5', actions=[Action{name='1'}, Action{name='2'}, Action{name='3'}, Action{name='4'}, Action{name='5'}, Action{name='6'}]}

2020-12-30 21:17:27.11: Command-2:Action-1 executing on Thread 'ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5' executing for 207ms
2020-12-30 21:17:27.11: Command-4:Action-1 executing on Thread 'ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9' executing for 930ms
2020-12-30 21:17:27.11: Command-1:Action-1 executing on Thread 'ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3' executing for 948ms
2020-12-30 21:17:27.11: Command-3:Action-1 executing on Thread 'ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-7' executing for 173ms
2020-12-30 21:17:27.11: Command-5:Action-1 executing on Thread 'ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-11' executing for 348ms
2020-12-30 21:17:27.314: Command-3:Action-2 executing on Thread 'ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-7' executing for 890ms
2020-12-30 21:17:27.345: Command-2:Action-2 executing on Thread 'ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5' executing for 178ms
2020-12-30 21:17:27.485: Command-5:Action-2 executing on Thread 'ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-11' executing for 702ms
2020-12-30 21:17:27.485: Command-5:Action-3 executing on Thread 'ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-15' executing for 161ms
2020-12-30 21:17:27.532: Command-2:Action-3 executing on Thread 'ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5' executing for 201ms
2020-12-30 21:17:27.657: Command-5:Action-4 executing on Thread 'ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-15' executing for 257ms
2020-12-30 21:17:27.735: Command-2:Action-4 executing on Thread 'ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5' executing for 518ms
2020-12-30 21:17:27.919: Command-5:Action-5 executing on Thread 'ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-15' executing for 258ms
2020-12-30 21:17:28.06: Command-4:Action-2 executing on Thread 'ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9' executing for 926ms
2020-12-30 21:17:28.075: Command-1:Action-2 executing on Thread 'ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3' executing for 413ms
2020-12-30 21:17:28.184: Command-5:Action-6 executing on Thread 'ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-15' executing for 77ms
2020-12-30 21:17:28.216: Command-3:Action-3 executing on Thread 'ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-7' executing for 487ms
2020-12-30 21:17:28.263: Command-2:Action-5 executing on Thread 'ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5' executing for 570ms
2020-12-30 21:17:28.497: Command-1:Action-3 executing on Thread 'ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3' executing for 273ms
2020-12-30 21:17:28.716: Command-3:Action-4 executing on Thread 'ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-7' executing for 302ms
2020-12-30 21:17:28.833: Command-2:Action-6 executing on Thread 'ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-5' executing for 202ms
2020-12-30 21:17:28.992: Command-4:Action-3 executing on Thread 'ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9' executing for 733ms
2020-12-30 21:17:29.024: Command-3:Action-5 executing on Thread 'ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-7' executing for 756ms
2020-12-30 21:17:29.727: Command-4:Action-4 executing on Thread 'ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9' executing for 131ms
2020-12-30 21:17:29.78: Command-3:Action-6 executing on Thread 'ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-7' executing for 920ms
2020-12-30 21:17:29.858: Command-4:Action-5 executing on Thread 'ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9' executing for 305ms
2020-12-30 21:17:30.168: Command-4:Action-6 executing on Thread 'ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-9' executing for 612ms
2020-12-30 21:17:30.715: Command-3:Action-7 executing on Thread 'ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-7' executing for 330ms
```

### Executors Implementation

```
package executors;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class CommandActionExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Initialize some starting params
        Random random = new Random();
        int maxActions = 20;
        int maxCommands = 5;

        // Generate some commands, with a random number of actions.
        // We'll use the indexes as the command and action names to keep it simple/readable
        List<Command> commands = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Integer c = 0; c < maxCommands; c++) {
            Command command = new Command(String.format("%d", c+1));
            for(Integer a = 0; a < random.nextInt(maxActions); a++) {
                Action action = new Action(random, String.format("%d", a+1));
                command.addAction(action);
            }
            commands.add(command);
        }

        // Print out the commands we'll execute, again to keep the results readable/understandable
        System.out.println("Commands to execute: \n" + commands.stream().map(Command::toString).collect(Collectors.joining("\n")) + "\n");

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);
        for(Command command:commands) executorService.submit(command);

        // When we execute the results, the actions should be executed in-order within a command at some point in the future
        // (not started all at once), so something like:
        // 0  Command-2:Action-1 scheduled at 34
        // 0  Command-1:Action-1 scheduled at 21
        // 0  Command-3:Action-1 scheduled at 4
        // 4  Command-3:Action2 scheduled at ...
        // 21 Command-1:Action-2 scheduled at ...
        // 34 Command-1-Action-2 scheduled at ...
        // ...
        // Now how to test this...Maybe with JUnit inOrder.verify(...).run() ?

    }

    public static class Action implements Runnable {

        private Command command;
        private final Random random;
        private final String name;

        public Action(Random random, String name) {
            this.random = random;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void setCommand(Command command) {
            this.command = command;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

            // Simply sleep for a random period of time. This simulates pieces of work being done (network request, etc.)
            long msTime = random.nextInt(1000);
            System.out.println(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ": Command-" + command.name + ":Action-" + name + " executing on Thread '" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "' executing for " + msTime + "ms");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(msTime);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Action{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    public static class Command implements Runnable {

        private final String name;
        private final List<Action> actions = new ArrayList<>();

        public Command(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void addAction(Action action) {
            action.setCommand(this);
            actions.add(action);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // If there are no actions, then do nothing
            if(actions.isEmpty()) return;

            ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(); // Because there is only one thread, this has the effect of executing sequentially and blocking
            for(Action action:actions) executor.submit(action);

        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Command{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", actions=" + actions +
                    '}';
        }
    }

}
```

#### Result

Output and schedule are as expected

```
2020-12-31 09:43:09.952: Command-3:Action-1 executing on Thread 'pool-4-thread-1' executing for 632ms
2020-12-31 09:43:09.952: Command-4:Action-1 executing on Thread 'pool-3-thread-1' executing for 932ms
2020-12-31 09:43:09.952: Command-2:Action-1 executing on Thread 'pool-6-thread-1' executing for 586ms
2020-12-31 09:43:09.952: Command-5:Action-1 executing on Thread 'pool-5-thread-1' executing for 987ms
2020-12-31 09:43:09.952: Command-1:Action-1 executing on Thread 'pool-2-thread-1' executing for 706ms
2020-12-31 09:43:10.562: Command-2:Action-2 executing on Thread 'pool-6-thread-1' executing for 329ms
2020-12-31 09:43:10.608: Command-3:Action-2 executing on Thread 'pool-4-thread-1' executing for 503ms
2020-12-31 09:43:10.891: Command-2:Action-3 executing on Thread 'pool-6-thread-1' executing for 443ms
2020-12-31 09:43:10.9: Command-4:Action-2 executing on Thread 'pool-3-thread-1' executing for 866ms
2020-12-31 09:43:10.955: Command-5:Action-2 executing on Thread 'pool-5-thread-1' executing for 824ms
2020-12-31 09:43:11.346: Command-2:Action-4 executing on Thread 'pool-6-thread-1' executing for 502ms
2020-12-31 09:43:11.766: Command-4:Action-3 executing on Thread 'pool-3-thread-1' executing for 638ms
2020-12-31 09:43:11.779: Command-5:Action-3 executing on Thread 'pool-5-thread-1' executing for 928ms
2020-12-31 09:43:11.848: Command-2:Action-5 executing on Thread 'pool-6-thread-1' executing for 179ms
2020-12-31 09:43:12.037: Command-2:Action-6 executing on Thread 'pool-6-thread-1' executing for 964ms
2020-12-31 09:43:12.412: Command-4:Action-4 executing on Thread 'pool-3-thread-1' executing for 370ms
2020-12-31 09:43:12.709: Command-5:Action-4 executing on Thread 'pool-5-thread-1' executing for 204ms
2020-12-31 09:43:12.783: Command-4:Action-5 executing on Thread 'pool-3-thread-1' executing for 769ms
2020-12-31 09:43:12.913: Command-5:Action-5 executing on Thread 'pool-5-thread-1' executing for 188ms
2020-12-31 09:43:13.102: Command-5:Action-6 executing on Thread 'pool-5-thread-1' executing for 524ms
2020-12-31 09:43:13.555: Command-4:Action-6 executing on Thread 'pool-3-thread-1' executing for 673ms
2020-12-31 09:43:13.634: Command-5:Action-7 executing on Thread 'pool-5-thread-1' executing for 890ms
2020-12-31 09:43:14.23: Command-4:Action-7 executing on Thread 'pool-3-thread-1' executing for 147ms
2020-12-31 09:43:14.527: Command-5:Action-8 executing on Thread 'pool-5-thread-1' executing for 538ms
```

Comment: For getting opinions on working code, consider visiting https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that existed :D